# How to parametrize newminted environments in the point of use

Tags: listings, minted, environment-variables

In my tex files I currently have the following newminted definitions for various Java code listings.

```
\newminted[javacode]{java}{%
    tabsize=4,
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    xleftmargin=30pt,
    linenos
}

\newminted[javacodeNoLines]{java}{%
    tabsize=4,
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    xleftmargin=30pt
}
```

and then I can do either `\begin{javacode}` or `\begin{javacodeNoLines}`.

But if I am to change some parameters in the `javacode` definition I would have to change them in `javacodeNoLines` as well. And the only difference of the two is that the former has one more option (`linenos`). I would like if possible to just have `javacodeNoLines` and at the point of use choose whether to pass an additional option or not.

I tried the following but they don't work.

```
\begin{javacodeNoLines}{linenos=}
...
\being{javacodeNoLines}[linenos=]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the “numbered line” version in terms of the `NoLines` one.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\newminted[javacodeNoLines]{java}{%
    tabsize=4,
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    xleftmargin=30pt
}

\newenvironment{javacode}
 {\VerbatimEnvironment\begin{javacodeNoLines*}{linenos}}
 {\end{javacodeNoLines*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{javacode}
/* This is a simple Java program. 
   FileName : "HelloWorld.java". */
class HelloWorld 
{ 
    // Your program begins with a call to main(). 
    // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window. 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        System.out.println("Hello, World"); 
    } 
}
\end{javacode}

\begin{javacodeNoLines}
/* This is a simple Java program. 
   FileName : "HelloWorld.java". */
class HelloWorld 
{ 
    // Your program begins with a call to main(). 
    // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window. 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        System.out.println("Hello, World"); 
    } 
}
\end{javacodeNoLines}

\end{document}
```

[image]

When you do `\newminted[foo]{language}`, the package actually defines two new environments, namely `foo` and `foo*`.

The former accepts no option, the latter instead wants a mandatory argument (in braces) with additional `minted` options to be evaluated and this is the feature I exploit in the code above.

Comment: Thx! That works. But what is the difference of ```javacodeNoLines``` and ```javacodeNoLines*```?

Comment: @GeorgeKastrinis I'll add a note

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation. Now it makes sense